# Finding complementary pairs

Tags: javascript, algorithm, programming-challenge, recursion

I've read the docs online explaining Log N and I do understand that the basic concept of it, but I'm still not sure I've managed to nail it.

> **The problem**
>
> This exercise is called *"Complementary Pairs"* and given an array *A*
>   and an integer *K*, how many pairs of *A*, sum to *K*.
>
> For example, with this input:
>
> ```
> k = 6 a = [1, 8, -3, 0, 1, 3, -2, 4, 5]
> ```
>
> we would have 7 possibilities, like i, j = (5, 5) to add 3 + 3, then the
>   pairs that add 1 + 5 (and the reverse), etc.
>
> **Naive solution**
>
> A first very naive solution is to for a \$O(N^2)\$ complexity
>   loop where you just bluntly search the array in two nested loops.

**\$N * Log N\$ Solution**

From my understanding a proper \$Log N\$ solution has to include a binary search like quicksort or mergesort, so I applied a divide and conquer algorithm where I split the array in two, until it's down to one element, then I assemble back again, and I for a \$N*N\$ search on array, checking which elements of the first added with the second add to constant *K*.

Although this is very similar to mergesort, it just doesn't feel a \$N * Log N\$ solution, because the worst case, the last recursion step, I'm doing \$N/2 * N/2\$ and for me that's just \$N*N\$ over time.

Here is the working solution:

```
var complementary_pairs = function (input, k) {

  // Base scenario
  if (input.length == 1) {    
    return input[0] * 2 == k ? 1 : 0
  }

  // Recursion
  var middle = Math.ceil(input.length / 2)
    , firstArray = input.slice(0, middle)
    , secondArray = input.slice(middle)

  var count = complementary_pairs(firstArray, k)
    + complementary_pairs(secondArray, k)

  // Problem condition
  for (var i = 0; i < firstArray.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < secondArray.length; j++) {
      if (firstArray[i] + secondArray[j] == k) {
        count += 2
      }
    }
  }

  return count

}

console.log(complementary_pairs([1, 8, -3, 0, 1, 3, -2, 4, 5], 6))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I might have missed something but I think I do have an `O(n*log(n))` solution.

Assuming `A` is your array of size n and `K` is the integer.

- Sort `A` with a efficient sorting algorithm (mergesort, quicksort, etc) : this is `O(n*log(n))`
- For each element `x` in `A`:

  - Use binary search to find the first occurrence of `K-x` (if any) : this is `O(log(n))`
  - Use binary search to find the last occurrence if `K-x` (if any) : this is `O(log(n))`

    -> These steps allow you to find the number of instances of `K-x` in `O(log(n))`

  ->This allows you to count the number of pairs in `O(n*log(n))`. Each pair has been counted twice.

Many minimal optimisations could be performed :

- Handling the identical values of `x` in one go
- Looping could stop when `2*x > K`
- Binary search could be limited to a smaller sub-array as we progress through `A`
- Etc

Please let me know if I missed something.

**Edit :** 
Here's a quick attempt with an initial array containing the original array twice to make testing somewhat easier.

I've included different versions, more and more optimised. One could go further but I started to have doubts about the correctness :-)

[Corresponding jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZYKPZ/)

```
var a = [1, 8, -3, 0, 1, 3, -2, 4, 5, 1, 8, -3, 0, 1, 3, -2, 4, 5];
var target = 6;
a.sort(function(a, b) {return a - b});

function binarySearch(a, k, lastOcc, min)
{
        var min = (typeof(min)==='undefined') ? 0 : min
        var max = a.length-1
        while (min <= max)
        {
            var range = max-min
            var midf = min + (range / 2)
            var mid = lastOcc ? Math.ceil(midf) : Math.floor(midf)
            var x = a[mid]
            if      (x < k) min = mid+1
            else if (x > k) max = mid-1
            else if (min==max) return mid
            else if (lastOcc) min = mid
            else              max = mid
        }
        return -1
}

// Zeroth solution
var count = 0
for (var i=0; i<a.length; i++)
{
    for (var j=0; j<a.length; j++)
    {
        if (a[i]+a[j]==target) count++
    }
}
console.log(count)

// First solution
var count = 0
for (var i=0; i<a.length; i++)
{
    var v = a[i]
    var x = target-v
    var f = binarySearch(a,x,false)
    if (f>-1)
    {
        var l = binarySearch(a,x,true)
        var nb = 1+l-f
        count+=nb
    }
}
console.log(count)

// Second solution - skipping over identical values
var count = 0
for (var i=0; i<a.length; i++)
{
    var v = a[i]
    var coef = 1
    while (i+1<a.length && a[i+1]==v)
    {
        coef++
        i++
    }
    var x = target-v
    var f = binarySearch(a,x,false)
    if (f>-1)
    {
        var l = binarySearch(a,x,true)
        var nb = 1+l-f
        count+=nb*coef
    }
}
console.log(count)

// Third solution - stopping once enough is enough
var count = 0
for (var i=0; i<a.length; i++)
{
    var v = a[i]
    var coef = 1
    while (i+1<a.length && a[i+1]==v)
    {
        coef++
        i++
    }
    var x = target-v
    if (v <= x)
    {
        if (v != x) coef*=2
        var f = binarySearch(a,x,false)
        if (f>-1)
        {
            var l = binarySearch(a,x,true)
            var nb = 1+l-f
            count+=nb*coef
        }
    }
    else break
}
console.log(count)

// Fourth solution - limiting the binary search to a smaller scope
var count = 0
for (var i=0; i<a.length; i++)
{
    var oldi=i
    var v = a[i]
    var coef = 1
    while (i+1<a.length && a[i+1]==v)
    {
        coef++
        i++
    }
    var x = target-v
    if (v < x)
    {
        var f = binarySearch(a,x,false,i)
        if (f>-1)
        {
            var l = binarySearch(a,x,true,f)
            var nb = 1+l-f
            count+=2*nb*coef
        }
    }
    else if (x==v)
    {
        count+=coef*coef
        break
    }
    else break
}
console.log(count)
```

**Re-edit :**

I've tested my code with the following inputs and all functions are returning the same values... but not in the same time.

```
var a = []
for (var i=0; i<10000; i++)
{
    a.push(Math.floor(Math.random()*20))
}
var target = a[0]+a[1]; // ensuring results
```

Zeroth solution is `O(n^2)`
First solution is `O(n*log(n) + n*log(n))` which is `O(n*log(n))`
Second solution is stricly better.
Third solution is stricly better.
Fourth solution is stricly better.

Comment: I think you don't need to *Use binary search to find the last occurrence if `K-x` (if any)*. Just go from the first one, and lineary check how many of them are.

Comment: I'm just missing what you mean by K-x. I though of sorting the array first, but I didn't see how could I traverse it with a O(n) complexity. I need to find all the pairs (x,x') where A[x] + A[x'] = k. Is that what you said?

Comment: @bitoiu `x` is an element of `a`, not an index. ;-) So, if `x = a[i]` for some `i`, you're looking for `K - x = K - a[i]` in the array. If you find it, i.e., you find `j` such that `a[j] = K - x = K - a[i]`, you've found a pair.

Comment: @VedranŠego I wanted to avoid checking *lineary* how many of them we have. Just to be safe, I'd rather perform 2 logarithmic operations. (It's not only about me being paranoid, I was mostly looking for a proof of concept)

Comment: @VedranŠego This being said, I now have doubts than binary search on first and last occurrences are actually. Let's implement this and see :-)

Comment: @VedranŠego can't thank you enough, but I really can't see how you do that search in log n time, that's probably, I can't seem to find the base case of recursion. sorry if I'm not being very helpful and this is trivial.

Comment: @Josay In extreme cases, 2 logs would be better, i.e., when you have at least log n equal elements in array. But, in an average case, I'd say linear would be better, because it's not linear in `n`, but in "the number of equal elements", which I wouldn't expect to grow over 2 or three. It would probably be better to make an associative array with each number repeated once and remembering how many times it occurs in the original array.

Comment: @bitoiu You don't need a recursion. The key is to use the fact that your array is sorted. You check the middle element. If it's to small, you go on to the right half of the array; if it's too big, you continue with left half. In each step you halve the part of array you need to search, thus doing so in at most `log_2 n` steps. Check it [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) and feel free to ask if you have trouble understanding something.

Comment: @bitoiu Here what I have so far : http://jsfiddle.net/v9ppL/1/
Not all optimisations have been performed but that's a start.

Comment: It's a bit late now, I'll check both Vedran and @Josey implementations tomorrow, I bet one or both have the right answer, thanks you very much. I'll reply tomorrow morning ;)

Comment: @VedranŠego, good suggestion on the iterative log n, I'll look into that as well

Comment: @Josay you can add the fiddle on top of your answer, it will help people detect it.

Comment: @Josay do you have a github account so when I commit the solution I mention this post and yourself?

Comment: @bitoiu No worries, my gitub account is https://github.com/SylvainDe .

Comment: if you want some d3 help with https://github.com/SylvainDe/VisualArrayAlgorithms let me know.

Answer (score 4):

This is not O(n log n) algorithm, because this part is quadratic:

```
  for (var i = 0; i < firstArray.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < secondArray.length; j++) {
      if (firstArray[i] + secondArray[j] == k) {
        count += 2
      }
    }
  }
```

Denoting `n = input.length`, this has roughly `(n/2)^2 = n^2/4` steps, which is O(n^2).

**The rest of this answer is a result of a misread and is not directly related to the question.** I'll leave it as a comment of a possibly extended exercise.

However, I'm not sure that O(n log n) algorithm does exist. Consider

```
a = [ 1, 2, 4, 8, ..., 2^n ] (for some n)
```

and `k` is a sum of all elements in `a`. Since you can repeat the numbers, and `a[k] = 2*a[k-1]` for all positive `k`, you'd have exponential number of sums, so no O(n log n) algorithm will solve this.

It is easy to show that the number of solutions is strictly bigger than 2^n. Just note that

```
k = (sum of ANY elements in a except a[0] = 1) + (sum of the remaining elements in a) * 1.
```

The first sum can be chosen in 2^n ways. Of course, there are other sums as well, but this is enough to show that you can have an exponential number of solutions, which is enough to show that no sub-exponential algorithm can find them all.

Of course, there may be a mathematical trick to compute only how many such solutions there are, but I don't know it.

Comment: thanks for a great answer, I took this exercise from a repo which has some codility exercises: https://github.com/bitoiu/codility/tree/master/complementary_pairs. It specifically asks for a sub quadratic answer, but like you say, this might dwell on a number trick that would make computing it more trivial. thanks again.

Comment: Scratch that. I've missed the part about **pairs**. My answer proved only that **all sums** cannot be found in sub-exponential time (actually, sometimes such problem has infinitely many solutions!). IMO, you should accept one of the other two answers instead of mine.

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me you can get faster than quadratic if you sort the list first, and use an algorithm like this... ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v9ppL/4/))

```
function complementaryPairs(a, target) {
    var count = 0,
        left = 0,
        right = a.length - 1,
        i;
    a.sort(function (a, b) {
        return a - b
    }); // [-3, -2, 0, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 8]

    // Eliminate arrays that can't contain any pairs
    if (a[left] * 2 > target || a[right] * 2 < target) {
        return 0;
    }
    for (; left <= right && a[left] * 2 <= target; left++) {
        // Get rid of any values on the right that are too large 
        while (right > left && a[left] + a[right] > target) right--;
        // Count values in between left and right which match with left
        for (i = right; i > left && a[left] + a[i] == target; i--) {
            count += 2;
        }
    }
    // Any values that are exactly half the target can also complement themselves
    // so count them again
    while (a[--left] * 2 == target) {
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

As the starting point for `right` decreases upon each cycle of `left`, it must be less than quadratic, right? (I'm happy to be corrected on this.)

And the built in sort is, as far as I know, O(n log n), so we can use it without increasing the order of complexity. (Of course in a high level language this becomes irrelevant because any built in function is likely to be much faster than one we would write ourselves).

Edit: here's an alternative version which I think is slightly faster and makes it easier to see how it works. This is pretty clearly O(n), apart from the initial `sort` (isn't it...?) ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v9ppL/12/))

```
function complementaryPairs(a, target) {
    var count = 0;
    a.sort(function (a, b) {
        return a - b
    }); 
    for (var left = 0, right = a.length - 1; left < right;) {
        if (a[left] + a[right] < target) {
            left++;
        } else if (a[left] + a[right] > target) {
            right--;
        } else if (a[left] == a[right]) {
            // Shortcut if the value is target / 2
            return count + (right - left + 1) * (right - left + 1)
        } else {
            // Found complementary pair. Move towards middle, counting duplicates.
            for (var leftCount = 1; a[left] == a[++left]; leftCount++);
            for (var rightCount = 1; a[right] == a[--right]; rightCount++);
            count += leftCount * rightCount * 2;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: the inner loop for / for is always quadratic even if it's not pure n*n

Comment: @bitoiu It's not. Notice that `j` is never reset. This means it gets to go only **once** from `a.length - 1` down to, in the worst case, zero during an execution of a program. That makes the first inner loop overall linear in `a.length`. The second one (by `k`) is similar.

Comment: @VedranŠego I might have this assumption wrong, that anything which is N* (N -C), whatever C, this will eventually lead to N*N? again, might be me being a noob.

Comment: @bitoiu The point is that C is not a constant but is increasing with each iteration of the outer loop

Comment: @bitoiu Consider this: `for (i = 0; i < n; i += 2) for (j = i; j % 7 > 0; j++) k++;` It's two loops, but the inner one runs at most 7 times each time, so it runs at most `7n/2` times. It's linear. In Stuart's code, consider only variable `j` and ignore the second inner loop for a moment. What happens with `j`? It starts  from `j = a.length - 1` and stops, if not before, when `j = 0` (because `j > i >= 0`). It happens through many steps of the outer loop, but it still catches each value only once and, hence, gets at most `a.length - 1` steps. I hope it is more clear now.

Comment: @Stuart There is an ambiguity in question. If you have `a=[1,1],k=2`, is the solution 2 (the first `1` summed with itself, and the second `1` summed with itself), or is it 4 (counting also first+second and second+first)? :-) If the later is true (as I think makes sense), your last loop needs fixing (instead of `count++` it needs `tmp++;` and, after the loop, `count+=tmp*tmp;`).

Comment: @VedranŠego The latter is true, and this is exactly what it currently does. Check the jsfiddle.

Comment: Just trying to catch up, pairs like (1,1) count once, for my example output it returns 7, 3 pairs and a mirror index for position f(5,5) = (3,3)

Answer (score 1):

Using a dictionary to look up is better:

```
private static int solution(int k, int[] arr) {
    Map<Integer, Boolean> map = new HashMap<Integer, Boolean>();
    for(int item: arr) {
        map.put(item, true);
    }
    int count = 0;
    for(int item: arr) {
        int temp = k - item;
        if(map.containsKey(temp)) {
            count ++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Hello duybinh0208, you should explain why using the dictionary is better than the approach the OP provided, this makes for a better review :)

Comment: You will get an up vote if you answer @IEatBagels question.

Answer (score 0):

This is computable in linear time by creating a hashtable (H) mapping each value in the array to the number of times it appears (a multiset).

```
A: [1, 8, -3, 0, 1, 3, -2, 4, 5] }
H: { -3 => 1, -2 => 1, 0 => 1, 1 => 2, 3 => 1, 4 => 1, 5 => 1, 8 => 1 }
```

Then the number of complementary pairs is

```
sum(over i in H.keys) { h[i] * h[K-i]) / 2 }
```